# Active record select with array passed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, select

How would I show all tickets with status.name equal to the items in the array?

A single item with select seems to work like so

```
@project_tickets = @project.tickets.select { |m| m.status.name == "new"] }
```

but not with an array of items

```
params[:array_here] = ["new","implemented"]

@project = Project.find_by_id(params[:project_id])
@project_tickets = @project.tickets.select { |m| m.status.name == [params[:array_here]] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your asking for is like this:

```
@project_tickets = @project.tickets.select { |m| params[:array_here].include? m.status.name }
```

But you should really be delegating this to the database.

```
@project_tickets = Ticket.includes(:status).where(:project_id => @project.id, :status => { :name => params[:array_here] })
```

Answer (score 0):

Does not `where` work?

```
@project_tickets = @project.tickets.where("name = ?", params[:array_here])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @new_tickets=@project.tickets.select { |m| m.status.name == params[:array_here][0] }

 @implemented_tickets=@project.tickets.select { |m| m.status.name == params[:array_here][1] }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
params[:array_here] = ["new","implemented"]

@project = Project.find_by_id(params[:project_id])
@project_tickets = @project.tickets.select { |m| params[:array_here].include?(m.status.name) }
```